# JavaFX - update UI on mouse click event

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How can I force canvas update immediately a shape after mouse button click event? Unfortunately the code bellow updates the values but does not repaint the canvas (see figure).

Threre is addEventFilter method, which updates (correctly) value of Candle object. Unfortunately even the values seem to be correct, the UI does not refresh the values.

[image]

```
/*
 Copyright 2014 Zoi Capital, LLC
 License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * A candlestick chart is a style of bar-chart used primarily to describe price
 * movements of a security, derivative, or currency over time.
 *
 * The Data Y value is used for the opening price and then the close, high and
 * low values are stored in the Data's extra value property using a
 * CandleStickExtraValues object.
 *
 *
 */
public class CandleStickChart extends XYChart<String, Number> {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CandleStickChart.class.getName());
    protected int maxBarsToDisplay;
    protected ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> dataSeries;
    protected BarData lastBar;
    protected NumberAxis yAxis;
    protected CategoryAxis xAxis;

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     *            The chart title
     * @param bars
     *            The bars data to display in the chart.
     */
    public CandleStickChart(String title, List<BarData> bars) {
        this(title, bars, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     *            The chart title
     * @param bars
     *            The bars to display in the chart
     * @param maxBarsToDisplay
     *            The maximum number of bars to display in the chart.
     */
    public CandleStickChart(String title, List<BarData> bars, int maxBarsToDisplay) {
        this(title, new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis(), bars, maxBarsToDisplay);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new CandleStickChart with the given axis.
     *
     * @param title
     *            The chart title
     * @param xAxis
     *            The x axis to use
     * @param yAxis
     *            The y axis to use
     * @param bars
     *            The bars to display on the chart
     * @param maxBarsToDisplay
     *            The maximum number of bars to display on the chart.
     */
    public CandleStickChart(String title, CategoryAxis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis, List<BarData> bars,
            int maxBarsToDisplay) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
        this.xAxis = xAxis;
        this.yAxis = yAxis;
        this.maxBarsToDisplay = maxBarsToDisplay;

        yAxis.autoRangingProperty().set(true);
        yAxis.forceZeroInRangeProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        setTitle(title);
        setAnimated(true);
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/styles/CandleStickChartStyles.css").toExternalForm());
        xAxis.setAnimated(true);
        yAxis.setAnimated(true);
        verticalGridLinesVisibleProperty().set(false);
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        List<BarData> sublist = getSubList(bars, maxBarsToDisplay);
        for (BarData bar : sublist) {
            String label = "";
            label = sdf.format(bar.getDateTime().getTime());
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(label, bar.getOpen(), bar));
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Adding bar with date/time: {0}", bar.getDateTime().getTime());
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Adding bar with price: {0}", bar.getOpen());
        }

        dataSeries = FXCollections.observableArrayList(series);

        setData(dataSeries);
        lastBar = sublist.get(sublist.size() - 1);
    }

    /**
     * Defines a formatter to use when formatting the y-axis values.
     *
     * @param formatter
     *            The formatter to use when formatting the y-axis values.
     */
    public void setYAxisFormatter(DecimalAxisFormatter formatter) {
        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(formatter);
    }

    /**
     * Appends a new bar on to the end of the chart.
     *
     * @param bar
     *            The bar to append to the chart
     */
    public void addBar(BarData bar) {

        if (dataSeries.get(0).getData().size() >= maxBarsToDisplay) {
            dataSeries.get(0).getData().remove(0);
        }

        int datalength = dataSeries.get(0).getData().size();
        dataSeries.get(0).getData().get(datalength - 1).setYValue(bar.getOpen());
        dataSeries.get(0).getData().get(datalength - 1).setExtraValue(bar);
        String label = sdf.format(bar.getDateTime().getTime());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Adding bar with actual time:  {0}", bar.getDateTime().getTime());
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Adding bar with formated time: {0}", label);

        lastBar = new BarData(bar.getDateTime(), bar.getClose(), bar.getClose(), bar.getClose(), bar.getClose(), 0);
        Data<String, Number> data = new XYChart.Data<>(label, lastBar.getOpen(), lastBar);
        dataSeries.get(0).getData().add(data);

    }

    /**
     * Update the "Last" price of the most recent bar
     *
     * @param price
     *            The Last price of the most recent bar.
     */
    public void updateLast(double price) {
        if (lastBar != null) {
            lastBar.update(price);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Updating last bar with date/time: {0}", lastBar.getDateTime().getTime());

            int datalength = dataSeries.get(0).getData().size();
            dataSeries.get(0).getData().get(datalength - 1).setYValue(lastBar.getOpen());

            dataSeries.get(0).getData().get(datalength - 1).setExtraValue(lastBar);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Updating last bar with formatteddate/time: {0}",
                    dataSeries.get(0).getData().get(datalength - 1).getXValue());
        }
    }

    protected List<BarData> getSubList(List<BarData> bars, int maxBars) {
        List<BarData> sublist;
        if (bars.size() > maxBars) {
            return bars.subList(bars.size() - 1 - maxBars, bars.size() - 1);
        } else {
            return bars;
        }
    }

    // -------------- METHODS
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Called to update and layout the content for the plot
     */
    @Override
    protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
        // we have nothing to layout if no data is present
        if (getData() == null) {
            return;
        }
        // update candle positions
        for (int seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < getData().size(); seriesIndex++) {
            Series<String, Number> series = getData().get(seriesIndex);
            Iterator<Data<String, Number>> iter = getDisplayedDataIterator(series);
            Path seriesPath = null;
            if (series.getNode() instanceof Path) {
                seriesPath = (Path) series.getNode();
                seriesPath.getElements().clear();
            }
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Data<String, Number> item = iter.next();
                double x = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item));
                double y = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item));
                Node itemNode = item.getNode();
                BarData bar = (BarData) item.getExtraValue();
                if (itemNode instanceof Candle && item.getYValue() != null) {
                    Candle candle = (Candle) itemNode;

                    double close = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(bar.getClose());
                    double high = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(bar.getHigh());
                    double low = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(bar.getLow());
                    double candleWidth = 10;
                    // update candle
                    candle.update(close - y, high - y, low - y, candleWidth, false, false);

                    // update tooltip content
                    String signal = "none";
                    if(candle.longSignal || candle.shortSignal) {
                        signal = "";
                        if(candle.longSignal) {
                            signal += "Buy";
                        }
                        if(candle.shortSignal) {
                            signal += "Sell";
                        }
                    }
                    candle.updateTooltip(bar.getOpen(), bar.getClose(), bar.getHigh(), bar.getLow(), signal);

                    // position the candle
                    candle.setLayoutX(x);
                    candle.setLayoutY(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dataItemChanged(Data<String, Number> item) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void dataItemAdded(Series<String, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<String, Number> item) {
        Node candle = createCandle(getData().indexOf(series), item, itemIndex);
        if (shouldAnimate()) {
            candle.setOpacity(0);
            getPlotChildren().add(candle);
            // fade in new candle
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), candle);
            ft.setToValue(1);
            ft.play();
        } else {
            getPlotChildren().add(candle);
        }
        // always draw average line on top
        if (series.getNode() != null) {
            series.getNode().toFront();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dataItemRemoved(Data<String, Number> item, Series<String, Number> series) {
        final Node candle = item.getNode();
        if (shouldAnimate()) {
            // fade out old candle
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), candle);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.setOnFinished((ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {
                getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
            });
            ft.play();
        } else {
            getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void seriesAdded(Series<String, Number> series, int seriesIndex) {
        // handle any data already in series
        for (int j = 0; j < series.getData().size(); j++) {
            Data item = series.getData().get(j);
            Node candle = createCandle(seriesIndex, item, j);
            if (shouldAnimate()) {
                candle.setOpacity(0);
                getPlotChildren().add(candle);
                // fade in new candle
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), candle);
                ft.setToValue(1);
                ft.play();
            } else {
                getPlotChildren().add(candle);
            }
        }
        // create series path
        Path seriesPath = new Path();
        seriesPath.getStyleClass().setAll("candlestick-average-line", "series" + seriesIndex);
        series.setNode(seriesPath);
        getPlotChildren().add(seriesPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void seriesRemoved(Series<String, Number> series) {
        // remove all candle nodes
        for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> d : series.getData()) {
            final Node candle = d.getNode();
            if (shouldAnimate()) {
                // fade out old candle
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), candle);
                ft.setToValue(0);
                ft.setOnFinished((ActionEvent actionEvent) -> {
                    getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
                });
                ft.play();
            } else {
                getPlotChildren().remove(candle);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new Candle node to represent a single data item
     *
     * @param seriesIndex
     *            The index of the series the data item is in
     * @param item
     *            The data item to create node for
     * @param itemIndex
     *            The index of the data item in the series
     * @return New candle node to represent the give data item
     */
    private Node createCandle(int seriesIndex, final Data item, int itemIndex) {
        Node candle = item.getNode();
        // check if candle has already been created
        if (candle instanceof Candle) {
            ((Candle) candle).setSeriesAndDataStyleClasses("series" + seriesIndex, "data" + itemIndex);
        } else {
            candle = new Candle("series" + seriesIndex, "data" + itemIndex);
            item.setNode(candle);
        }
        return candle;
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the range has been invalidated and we need to update
     * it. If the axis are auto ranging then we compile a list of all data that
     * the given axis has to plot and call invalidateRange() on the axis passing
     * it that data.
     */
    @Override
    protected void updateAxisRange() {
        // For candle stick chart we need to override this method as we need to
        // let the axis know that they need to be able
        // to cover the whole area occupied by the high to low range not just
        // its center data value
        final Axis<String> xa = getXAxis();
        final Axis<Number> ya = getYAxis();
        List<String> xData = null;
        List<Number> yData = null;
        if (xa.isAutoRanging()) {
            xData = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (ya.isAutoRanging()) {
            yData = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (xData != null || yData != null) {
            for (Series<String, Number> series : getData()) {
                for (Data<String, Number> data : series.getData()) {
                    if (xData != null) {
                        xData.add(data.getXValue());
                    }
                    if (yData != null) {
                        BarData extras = (BarData) data.getExtraValue();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            yData.add(extras.getHigh());
                            yData.add(extras.getLow());
                        } else {
                            yData.add(data.getYValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (xData != null) {
                xa.invalidateRange(xData);
            }
            if (yData != null) {
                ya.invalidateRange(yData);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Candle node used for drawing a candle
     */
    private class Candle extends Group {

        private final Line highLowLine = new Line();
        private final Region bar = new Region();
        private final Polygon longSignalArrow = new Polygon(3, 0, -2, 10, 8, 10);
        private final Polygon shortSignalArrow = new Polygon(0, 10, -5, 0, 5, 0);
        private boolean shortSignal = false;
        private boolean longSignal = false;
        private String seriesStyleClass;
        private String dataStyleClass;
        private boolean openAboveClose = true;
        private final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();

        private Candle(String seriesStyleClass, String dataStyleClass) {
            setAutoSizeChildren(false);
            getChildren().addAll(highLowLine, bar, longSignalArrow, shortSignalArrow);
            this.seriesStyleClass = seriesStyleClass;
            this.dataStyleClass = dataStyleClass;
            updateStyleClasses();
            tooltip.setGraphic(new TooltipContent());
            Tooltip.install(bar, tooltip);

            addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    if (mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        Candle c = (Candle) mouseEvent.getSource();
                        System.out.println("XXXXXX " + c.longSignal);
                        c.longSignal = !c.longSignal;
                    }
                    if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                        Candle c = (Candle) mouseEvent.getSource();
                        System.out.println("XXXXXX " + c.shortSignal);
                        c.shortSignal = !c.shortSignal;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void setSeriesAndDataStyleClasses(String seriesStyleClass, String dataStyleClass) {
            this.seriesStyleClass = seriesStyleClass;
            this.dataStyleClass = dataStyleClass;
            updateStyleClasses();
        }

        public void update(double closeOffset, double highOffset, double lowOffset, double candleWidth, boolean shortSig, boolean longSig) {
            openAboveClose = closeOffset > 0;
            updateStyleClasses();
            highLowLine.setStartY(highOffset);
            highLowLine.setEndY(lowOffset);
            longSignalArrow.setFill(Color.RED);
            shortSignalArrow.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            longSignalArrow.setTranslateX(8);
            shortSignalArrow.setTranslateX(8);
            final String cssDefault = "-fx-border-color: blue;\n"
                    + "-fx-border-insets: 5;\n"
                    + "-fx-border-width: 3;\n"
                    + "-fx-border-style: dashed;\n";
            shortSignalArrow.setStyle(cssDefault);
            longSignalArrow.setStyle(cssDefault);
            shortSignalArrow.setVisible(shortSignal);
            longSignalArrow.setVisible(longSignal);

            if (candleWidth == -1) {
                candleWidth = bar.prefWidth(-1);
            }
            if (openAboveClose) {
                bar.resizeRelocate(-candleWidth / 2, 0, candleWidth, closeOffset);
            } else {
                bar.resizeRelocate(-candleWidth / 2, closeOffset, candleWidth, closeOffset * -1);
            }
        }

        public void updateTooltip(double open, double close, double high, double low, String signal) {
            TooltipContent tooltipContent = (TooltipContent) tooltip.getGraphic();
            tooltipContent.update(open, close, high, low, signal);
        }

        private void updateStyleClasses() {
            getStyleClass().setAll("candlestick-candle", seriesStyleClass, dataStyleClass);
            highLowLine.getStyleClass().setAll("candlestick-line", seriesStyleClass, dataStyleClass,
                    openAboveClose ? "open-above-close" : "close-above-open");
            bar.getStyleClass().setAll("candlestick-bar", seriesStyleClass, dataStyleClass,
                    openAboveClose ? "open-above-close" : "close-above-open");
        }
    }

    private class TooltipContent extends GridPane {

        private final Label openValue = new Label();
        private final Label closeValue = new Label();
        private final Label highValue = new Label();
        private final Label lowValue = new Label();
        private final Label sigValue = new Label();

        private TooltipContent() {
            Label open = new Label("OPEN:");
            Label close = new Label("CLOSE:");
            Label high = new Label("HIGH:");
            Label low = new Label("LOW:");
            Label sig = new Label("SIG:");
            open.getStyleClass().add("candlestick-tooltip-label");
            close.getStyleClass().add("candlestick-tooltip-label");
            high.getStyleClass().add("candlestick-tooltip-label");
            low.getStyleClass().add("candlestick-tooltip-label");
            sig.getStyleClass().add("candlestick-tooltip-label");
            setConstraints(open, 0, 0);
            setConstraints(openValue, 1, 0);
            setConstraints(close, 0, 1);
            setConstraints(closeValue, 1, 1);
            setConstraints(high, 0, 2);
            setConstraints(highValue, 1, 2);
            setConstraints(low, 0, 3);
            setConstraints(lowValue, 1, 3);
            setConstraints(sig, 0, 4);
            setConstraints(sigValue, 1, 4);
            getChildren().addAll(open, openValue, close, closeValue, high, highValue, low, lowValue, sig, sigValue);
        }

        public void update(double open, double close, double high, double low, String signal) {
            openValue.setText(Double.toString(open));
            closeValue.setText(Double.toString(close));
            highValue.setText(Double.toString(high));
            lowValue.setText(Double.toString(low));
            sigValue.setText(signal);
        }
    }

    protected static CandleStickChart chart;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event filter (normally you would just use an event handler; is there any reason you are doing this differently?) should update the UI; you don't seem to do this. You want something like

```
setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {

    if (mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
        System.out.println("XXXXXX " + longSignal);
        longSignal = !longSignal;

        longSignalArrow.setVisible(longSignal);   
    }
    if (mouseEvent.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
        System.out.println("XXXXXX " + shortSignal);
        shortSignal = !shortSignal;

        shortSignalArrow.setVisible(shortSignal);
    }


});
```